# Erro 'else' without a previous 'if'

Tags: c

Estou com um problema e não sei como resolver.

O programa em  `C` que desenvolvi esta apresentando vários tipos de erros e não sei o que poderia ser:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main ()
{
    int SA, SN;
    int NOME, AUMENTO;
    printf ("NOME");
    scanf ("%f", &NOME);
    if (SA <= 400);
    SN= SA*1.12;
    AUMENTO="15%";
    else
    if (SA <=700);
    SN=SA*1,12;
    AUMENTO= "12%";
    else
    if (SA <=1000);
    SN=SA*1,1
    AUMENTO= "10%";
    else
    if (SA <= 1800);
    SN=SA*1,07;
    AUMENTO= "7%";
    else
    if (SA <=2500)
    SN=SA*1,04;
    AUMENTO= "4%";
    else
    AUMENTO="sem aumento"
    printf ("NOME: ", NOME, ",% de aumento: ", AUMENTO, ",Salario atual", SA, "Novo salário: ",SN);
    System ("PAUSE");
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: estou confuso com uma coisa, por que ele esta dando erro nas linha que estou utilizando %?

Comment: Tem uma técnica simples para descobrir o lugar dos erros, se chama "Dividir para Conquistar". Você faz assim, comenta a segunda metade do código, verifica se erros continuam, se continuam comenta a segunda metade do código que ficou e assim por diante, até encontrar o trecho com erro de compilação. Para C++ esta técnica deve prever as características da implementação OO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Código corrigido:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    float SA, SN;
    char NOME[30], AUMENTO[10];
    printf ("NOME");
    gets(NOME);
    printf("Informe SA: ");
    scanf("%f", &SA);
    if (SA <= 400) {
        SN = SA*1.15;
        strcpy(AUMENTO, "15%");
    }
    else
        if (SA <= 700) {
            SN = SA*1.12;
            strcpy(AUMENTO, "12%");
        }
        else
            if (SA <=1000) {
                SN = SA*1.1
                strcpy(AUMENTO, "10%");
            }
            else
                if (SA <= 1800) {
                    SN = SA*1.07;
                    strcpy(AUMENTO, "7%");
                }
                else
                    if (SA <= 2500) {
                        SN = SA*1.04;
                        strcpy(AUMENTO, "4%");
                    }
                    else {
                        SN = SA;
                        strcpy(AUMENTO, "sem aumento");
                    }
    printf ("NOME: %s, %% de aumento: %s, Salario atual: %.2f, Novo salário: %.2f\n", NOME, AUMENTO, SA, SN);
    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Mas note que poderia ficar muito mais simples, por exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    float SA, SN;
    char NOME[30];
    int AUMENTO;
    printf ("NOME");
    gets(NOME);
    printf("Informe Salário Atual: ");
    scanf("%f", &SA);
    if (SA <= 400)
        AUMENTO = 15;
    else
        if (SA <= 700)
            AUMENTO = 12;
        else
            if (SA <=1000)
                AUMENTO = 10;
            else
                if (SA <= 1800)
                    AUMENTO = 7;
                else
                    if (SA <= 2500)
                        AUMENTO = 4;
                    else
                        AUMENTO = 0;
    SN = SA * (float) (100 + AUMENTO) / 100;
    printf ("NOME: %s, %% de aumento: %d, Salario atual: %.2f, Novo salário: %.2f\n", NOME, AUMENTO, SA, SN);
    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: obrigado você não sabe o quanto tentei arrumar esses meus erros, com um tempo vou melhorando.

Comment: ugh! Parece Python :)

Answer (score 2):

Seu código não está com syntaxe de bloco correta, falta chaves para atribuir sequencia do código.

Exemplo:

```
if (SA <= 400){
  SN= SA*1.12;
  AUMENTO="15%";
}else{
  //continuando seus if...
}
```

Por isso ele dá erro dizendo que seu else, elseif não tem correspondente

Comment: já corrigi isso obrigado por me indicar isso.

Answer (score 1):

Dando uma primeira olhadela noto que o código tem imensos erros relacionados com ponto-e-virgula em falta em várias linhas, e em excesso nas linhas com **if**s. Também faltam chavetas nos blocos dos if.

Comment: Bem interessante sua resposta, mas quando for assim você pode pegar o código que ele postou e corrigir e enviar para ele de volta..

Comment: Isso deveria ser um comentário e não resposta.

Comment: Ah, ok, ok, peço desculpa. Sou maçarico por aqui, ainda estou a apanhar o jeito.